# Csla.Luna, what's this?

Tags: wpf, csla

I have this wpf form; the call to `InitializeComponent()` brings up this message:

> Binding Failure was detected.
>
> The assembly with display name
>   'Csla.Luna' failed to load in the
>   'Load' binding context of the
>   AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the
>   failure was:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could
>   not load file or assembly 'Csla.Luna,
>   Version=3.6.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=93be5fdc093e4c30' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.
>       File name: 'Csla.Luna, Version=3.6.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=93be5fdc093e4c30'
>
> ```
> === Pre-bind state information ===
> LOG: User = DOMAIN\blah.blah
> LOG: DisplayName = Csla.Luna, Version=3.6.1.0, Culture=neutral,
> ```
>
> PublicKeyToken=93be5fdc093e4c30
>        (Fully-specified)
>       LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/MyPath/bin/Debug/
>       LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>       Calling assembly : PresentationFramework,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
>       ===
>       LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>       LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   D:\MyPath\bin\Debug\Myapplication.vshost.exe.Config
>       LOG: Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
>       LOG: Post-policy reference: Csla.Luna, Version=3.6.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=93be5fdc093e4c30
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///D:/MyPath/bin/Debug/Csla.Luna.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///D:/MyPath/bin/Debug/Csla.Luna/Csla.Luna.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///D:/MyPath/bin/Debug/Csla.Luna.EXE.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///D:/MyPath/bin/Debug/Csla.Luna/Csla.Luna.EXE.

We use Csla but in a data access component that is not developed by me; 
I don't know what Csla.Luna is, and I couldn't find anything about it online. Any help?...

The only "out of the ordinary" thing that I am doing on that form is that I am binding to some ObjectDataProviders that call static methods accessing the database, but It worked so far, and I can't tell whether this is the problem or not.

Any help would be appreciated. Can't believe that Google has no clue about this Csla.Luna thing.

Comment: I'm getting the same sort of error, not in CSLA but in AvalonDock -- the runtime seems to think the Luna resource file is an assembly, and it doesn't load it.  I'll update here if I get any further.

Comment: In my case, that was not an actual exception thrown, but a debugger message. I was confused because i forgot i checked everything in the Debug>Exceptions dialog before running the code. Or I don't know, it could have been something else i checked and unchecked after, because now it works just fine.

It's kind of dissapointing to realize i don't really know my IDE :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Csla.Luna is part of the original framework. You should try and contact the person in charge of developing the data acces component to find out more about it.

In any case, it seem that you are missing this file (Csla.Luna.dll).

You could also use Reflector to pinpoint the location of the call to this Csla.Luna assembly...

Comment: The guy developing the data access framework has no clue about Csla.Luna. BUT now it turns out that was only a MDA message, and we can ignore it.